# Experiment: More aggressive review queue indicator

Tags: discussion

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, I announced [an experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445/1438) that would:

- Turn on the review queue indicator whenever there's a task available in any queue.
- All queues with at least one task will be marked with a red dot. There are no grey dots:

  [image: Inbox Zero indicator]

**This *will* mean you'll be notified of outstanding tasks you can't clear.** We are aware of a problem that people will be notified of queues that they don't have the privilege to access. That's next on the list to fix. The goal is to be more aggressive with the indicator to see if we can clear tasks more quickly. Please let us know if we've gone too far.

And in general, we're interested in any feedback to this change: positive, negative or noncommittal.

Comment: Big improvement! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

### Positive

It's immediately clear that there are review items in the queue. The previous grey dots were much less visible. There's much more color contrast now, I suppose that will benefit color blind users too.